# Automation - iTunes Producer

Tags: ios, automation, build-automation, automator, build-script

I am trying to get an automated process happening in iTunes producer.

We have thousands of songs that need to be uploaded as ringtones. We need the process to become a lot quicker.

We basically need to do the following on the 'Tone' screen under the 'info' section:
We have a spreadsheet with all the data required to fill out the form
We have a folder with all the audio files that need to be uploaded. (These need to be matched to the relevant row/info in the spread.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!